# Get Google Sheet ID from a Google Spreadsheet downloaded as an *.xlsx file

Tags: c#, excel, google-sheets, openxml

Google Sheets spreadsheets have multiple worksheets inside them:

[image]

Each of these worksheets have a unique ID associated with them. This ID appears as a part of the URL:

[image]

Here, the sheet ID is 5246224.

I'm using the Drive API to download the spreadsheet as an *.xlsx file, and I'm using the OpenXML library to read the Excel file. The problem is that I can't find that the worksheet with ID 5246224 is Sheet2 from the OpenXML worksheet.

Here's the code:

```cs
var sheetId = 5246224;

using (var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = this.creds
}))
{
    var driveRequest = service.Files.Export(spreadsheetId, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var response = driveRequest.DownloadWithStatus(stream);

    // Index out of range exception:
    var spreadsheet = new ExcelPackage(stream).Workbook.Worksheets[sheetId];
}
```

Previously, I used to use the Google Sheets API directly. As such, I only have sheetId available (not sheet name). I can't use the Google Sheets API due to low rate limits.

It's fine if I have to use something other than Excel or OpenXML. Is there a way to identify the worksheet given the sheet ID without calling the Google Sheets API?

Comment: I think that when Google Spreadsheet is converted to XLSX data, the sheet IDs are not used. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, for example, how about using the sheet name instead of the sheet ID? Because I think that the sheet name is not changed even when Google Spreadsheet is converted to XLSX data. If this was not your expected direction, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike I can't use sheet name since other parts of the application use sheet ID. If I'm able to find the sheet name given the sheet ID (which is available throughout the application) without calling the Sheets API, the problem would be solved.

Comment: Is this in Excel? If not, why use that tag?

Comment: @SolarMike The Spreadsheet is originally from Google Sheets stored on Drive. When it's downloaded via the Drive API, it is first exported to Excel (or .ods as per preference).

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I can't use sheet name since other parts of the application use sheet ID.`, I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation.